# How can I force a VS Code task to run regardless of failures of tasks which it depends on?

Tags: docker-compose, pytest, vscode-tasks

So I have a few tasks in vscode which enable some integration testing via docker...

I have a 'cleanup' task which is run, and depends on all of the tasks that are needed to spin up the environment, and run testing.

```json
{
            "label": "compose:test:cleanup",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down -v --remove-orphans",
            "group": "test",
            "dependsOn": [
                "compose:build",
                "compose:wait",
                "compose:migrate",
                "compose:seed",
                "compose:test"
            ]
        },
```

The details of each test are inconsequential, but you can see that I am building the containers, waiting for a stable database connection, running database migrations, seeding the database with some test data, then running the test task.

My test task uses pytest, so the problem is if any tests fail at all, the cleanup task is never run.

Is there a way to force the cleanup task to run regardless of failures? alternatively, is there a way to force pytest to fail quietly (i.e. `sys.exit(0)` even on failures)?

Comment: possibly (tangentially) related discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70283